# How to register a ELF file as a command?

Tags: bash, command-line, command

So I am trying to study assembly and there is a assembler that is given by a ELF file that can be simply downloaded in a zip file, but to execute this ELF file I find myself needing to put the entire adddres of the ELF file like in

```
/home/Dilho/FASMg/fasmg.x64
```

and then it runs as it should. How can I make this ELF file be registered as a executable command in the bash shell, just like the command prompt installed program htop ? That is, I can execute htop from any folder without having to make a explicit reference to where in my computer the executable ELF file for htop is located? Does this have anything to do with symbolic links? (probably not, right? since the ln command creates a local link in the folder that you are in).

Basically is there a way to make bash understand that whenever fasmg is written it always means /home/Dilho/FASMg/fasmg.x64 independant of the folder you are in?